# R great tables package - how to draw custom horizontal lines

Tags: r, gt

I would like to be able to draw custom horizontal lines at certain rows using R's gt package. I've worked out the remove the default horizontal lines but the code I'm trying (see the last two lines below), which gives no errors does not seem to draw any lines. Help appreciated.

```
require(gt)
        
gt(iris) %>% 
 tab_spanner(label = "Sepal", columns = c(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) %>% 
 tab_spanner(label = "Petal", columns = c(Petal.Length, Petal.Width)) %>%   
 cols_label(Sepal.Length = "Length", Sepal.Width = "Width") %>% 
  tab_options(table_body.hlines.color = "transparent")  %>% 
  tab_style(style = cell_borders(sides = c("bottom"),  weight = px(0.5)),
            locations = cells_body(rows = c(3, 4, 7)))
```

I would also be interested in how to draw a horizontal line across say only he first three columns for a given row but will post that as a separate question, should that be out of scope for one question.

Comment: have you tried defining the colour? It's supposed to default to black, but I don't know if the CSS styling overrides that with transparent?

Comment: Can you share your desired output

Comment: This similarly ran fine for me, but `gt` will sometimes have issues with borders because it sets some reasonable default styling. Regarding the horizontal only the first three columns, just add `columns = 1:3` to `cells_body()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, your code draws horizontal lines on the requested rows (3, 4, and 7). I just ran it and it works. Is this result what you expect?

[image: result]

Tested with `R 4.2.1`, `gt` package version `0.8.0` using `Rstudio 2022.12.0`

Comment: mmm... interesting ... I'm not getting the lines ... using R version 4.2.2 is the only difference.  Perhaps I'll try a reboot.

Comment: You can also try reinstalling the gt package, to make sure the imports are at the correct version. For example, ggplot2 is one of them and it should be at least version 3.3.5.

Comment: I tried rolling back to 4.2.1 but that did not help ... also reinstalled gt and ggplot2, then tried 4.2.2 but no joy ... something odd going on.  Will try my other laptop and see if it works there.

Comment: OK got it to work using sides = "top"  for some reason "bottom" does not want to work ...never give up never surrender!